# SELECT in DATEDIFF not working

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT creation_date
   FROM time_info
   WHERE is_on = 'yes'
   LIMIT 0,1),
   (SELECT creation_date
    FROM time_info
    WHERE is_on = 'no'
    LIMIT 0,1)
FROM time_info;
```

I want to calculate date difference, but things aren't working this way. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the error? Can you show some example data? Expected output?

Comment: @juergend: i need to take first date from database whose is_on='yes' and first whose is_on='no',and then i need to find the differance between two dates.

Comment: Please add **all** the necessary info well formatted in your question. That makes it easier for us and you get a better answer.

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will give you indeterminate results. When you say "first", you have to define better in what order something is considered first and what last.

Comment: there is no need for ORDER BY bcoz the primary key of table is auto incremented !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
set @date1:=(SELECT creation_date
   FROM time_info
   WHERE is_on = 'yes'
   LIMIT 0,1);

set @date2:=   (SELECT creation_date
    FROM time_info
    WHERE is_on = 'no'
    LIMIT 0,1);
select datediff(@date1,@date2);
```

You need to provide more information to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: worked for me. Thnx mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Your braces '(',')' are not balanced in the SELECT statement.

Comment: except for that...that is not the isssue !

Comment: It's one of the many issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(t1.creation_date,t2.creation_date )
   FROM time_info t1
   INNER JOIN time_info t2 ON t1.your_id_column = t2.your_id_column
   WHERE t1.is_on = 'yes'  AND t2.is_on = 'no';
```